RegEx/Power Automate Desktop: Capture all data from specific string to last pattern occurrence?
I'm attempting to use RegEx with Power Automate Desktop to match patterns from a specific string to the last occurring pattern:
Example list:
00_000_A.B.C.\_One_Room
Schrute_Dwight
Halpert_Jim
Scott_Michael
00_000_A.B.C.\_One_Room
Schrute_Dwight
Halpert_Jim
Scott_Michael
01_200_A.B.C.\_Two_Room
Schrute_Dwight
Halpert_Jim
Scott_Michael

In this example list, I'd like to parse all data starting from 00_000_A.B.C._One_Room to the last occurring pattern of LAST_FIRST before 01_200_A.B.C._Two_Room. I'm parsing this data to write to Excel.
Is this possible? (And is this possible with Power Automate Desktop?)
I'm new to RegEx, and I've been fiddling around with something like this:
00_000_A.B.C._One_Room(([A-Za-z]`_`+`_`[A-Za-z]+|\n)*)

I've attached an image with the results I get with this. All the data I want is highlighted in that tester... but Power Automate doesn't capture all of it - only one instance of the 00_000_A.B.C._One_Room.


Note that '00_000_A.B.C.\_One_Room' contains a backslash followed by an underscore (not an escaped underscore) but there is no backslash in the screen shot of "Test Strings". Similar for all other lines.

If power-automate supports lookaheads try (?:^.*\n)*(?=^01_200_A.B.C._Two_Room$). (?:^.*\n)* is greedy so lines will continue to be added until the next line is the last instance of the line '^01_200_A.B.C._Two_Room'. Demo

"...Power Automate doesn't capture all of it..." can you actualy use capture-groups for extraction in this tool? Also try e.g. 00_000_A\.B\.C\._One_Room((?:\r?\n[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+)+) or if no capturing with a lookbehind: (?<=00_000_A\.B\.C\._One_Room)(?:\r?\n[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+)+ (note that I added optional CR to newline).

Btw. it's a better idea to include the Regex101 demo-link than just showing an image.

@bobblebubble - Your solution worked!! Thank you so much!!! I'll be sure to add the demo-link for future Qs.
Thank you Cary as well! :)

@Laura That's good! May I ask which of the two regexes worked for you, the first one with the capture-group or the second with use of a lookbehind? Maybe this helps someone else too. If you like, post your working solution as answer, it's encouraged here also to self-answer.
